# Properties of Lebesgue Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and $T>0$ fixed. Let $f \in L^2(0,T; L^2(\Omega))$.

**Question 1.** Can I to afirmate that there exists $c>0$ such that
$$\int_0^T ||f(t)||^2_{L^2} \; dt<c?$$

Here, $||\cdot||_{L^2}$ denote the usual norm in $L^2(\Omega)$. I think yes, since the function $g:(0,T) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$g(t):=||f(t)||_{L^2},\; \forall \; t \in (0,T)$$
is such that $g \in L^2(0,T)$, that is,
$$\int_0^T ||f(t)||^2_{L^2} \; dt=\int_0^T |g(t)|^2_{L^2} \; dt <\infty$$

**Question 2.** I know that $L^2(0,T, L^2(\Omega))$ is continuous embedded in $L^1(0,T, L^2(\Omega))$. So, $g \in L^1(0,T)$, that is, $f \in L^1(0,T, L^2(\Omega))$? Moreover,
$$\int_0^T ||f(t)||_{L^2} \; dt<c?$$

Where $c>0$ is the same given in Question $1$.

**Definition.** Let $X=(X,||\cdot||_X)$ be a Banach space and $1 \leq p < \infty$. The space $L^p(0,T; X)$ consists of all measurable functions $u: (0,T) \rightarrow X$ for which
$$||u||_p:=\left ( \int_0^T ||u(t)||_X^p\;dt\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}< \infty $$
holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Question 1 is true. Indeed, from the definition of the norm in the space $L^p(0,T;X)$ with $p=2$ and $X=L^2(\Omega)$, we obtain
$$\left( \int_{0}^{T} \|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^{2} dt \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\|u\|_{L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))}<\infty \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{T} \|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^{2} dt<c<\infty.$$

To Question 2, observe that from Hölder's inequality (assuming that $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{T} \|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^{2} dt<c$)  we obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^{T} \|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)} dt&=&\int_{0}^{T} 1 \cdot\|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)} dt \\
&\leq& \left(\int_{0}^{T} 1^2dt\right)^\frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{0}^{T} \tag{*} \|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^{2} dt \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&<& T^{\frac{1}{2}}c^{\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Can I write also that, if $u \in L^2(0,T; L^2(\Omega))$, $$\int_0^T ||u(t)||_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq ||u||_{L^1(0,T; L^2(\Omega))}?$$ And there exists a relation between $c$ and $ ||u||_{L^1(0,T; L^2(\Omega))}$?

Comment: Do you mean $\int_{0}^{T} \|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega}dt \leq \|u\|_{L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))}?$

Comment: Observe that from definition $\int_{0}^{T}\|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}dt=\|u\|_{L^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))}$. From the second line in $(*)$ we obtain $\int_{0}^{T}\|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}dt \leq T^{\frac{1}{2}} \|u\|_{L^{2}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))}$. In general, in the embbedings of vector valued Lebesgue spaces there is a constant that depends on $T$ in the inequalities.

Comment: Understand. But using the fact that $ L^2 (0, T; L^2(\Omega)) \hookrightarrow L^1 (0, T; L^2(\Omega)) $, if $u \in L^2(0,T; L^2(\Omega)) \subset L^1(0,T; L^2(\Omega))$ can I get an estimate for $\int_{0}^{T} \|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega}dt$ in terms of $||u||_{L^1(0,T; L^2(\Omega))}$? Only in terms of  $||u||_{L^2(0,T; L^2(\Omega))}$ (as you wrote above)?

Comment: Yes, with a constant depending on $T$, namely $\int_{0}^{T}\|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}dt=\|u\|_{L^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))} \leq T^{\frac{1}{2}} \|u\|_{L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))}$. Note that the embbeding $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega)) \hookrightarrow L^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ is proved by using the Hölder's inequality as I did in $(*)$.

Comment: The estimate for $\int_{0}^{T}\|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}dt$ in terms of $\|u\|_{L^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))}$ is a equality, that is  $\int_{0}^{T}\|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}dt=\|u\|_{L^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))}$ (take $p=1$ and $X=L^2(\Omega)$ in the definition of $L^p(0,T;X)$.